# Does the httr package have a way to call the OPTIONS method?

Tags: python, r, request, httr

I am trying to replicate some code from python to R. The python requests module allows for requests.options calls to be made. These options allow me to see a handful of servers in which I need to access one from, but I don't see how this can be done in httr. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the generic `VERB` request. So something like

```
VERB("OPTIONS", "http://server.com")
```